# Which particular part of a windows application cause bugs like application hang,crash or terminate suddenly

Tags: windows, testing, crash, terminate

I need to know which part of a window application cause bugs like:

application hang
application crash
application terminated suddenly/unexpectedly

am sure possible bugs related to this may be database error, network problem. Mainly, i need to know this for testing purpose. If anyone know anything related to this please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Any part of an application can cause any of those symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience this kind of bugs arises

1. Unexpected Server(Database) stop, or to many connection in the pool
2. antivirus takes long time to scan application installation folder(ex.DLL)
3. if large amount of data storing in system memmory
4. improper garbage cleaning

etc